# Heroku/Auth0 Rules - Whitespace - .edu

Tags: heroku, rules, auth0

I am creating an application using Auth0 and Heroku, I would like to create a whitespace rule that allows only .edu addresses to be able to login.  However, the whitespace skeleton only shows for specific addresses.

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    //we just care about NameOfTheAppWithWhiteList
    //bypass this rule for every other app
    if(context.clientName !== 'NameOfTheAppWithWhiteList'){
      return callback(null, user, context);
    }

var whitelist = [ 'user1@mail.com', 'user2@mail.com' ]; //authorized users
var userHasAccess = whitelist.some(
  function (email) {
    return email === user.email;
  });

if (!userHasAccess) {
  return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Access denied.'));
}

callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Any advice on how to figure out how to solve this problem?  Im new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

This also works for email addresses from country-specific TLDs, such as `.edu.ar`:

```
var userHasAccess = email.split('@')[1].split('.').slice(-3, -1).indexOf('edu') !== -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to check if the email address ends with `.edu`:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (!/\.edu$/.test(user.email)) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Access denied.'));
  }

  callback(null, user, context);
}
```